# Image.HorizontalResolution and Image.VerticalResolution - why float?

Tags: .net, image, image-processing

This is partly out of curiosity and partly to be able to justify decision how to store in SQL Server database:

Why `Image.HorizontalResolution` and `Image.VerticalResolution` have type of floating-point number? How does "infinity" and "NaN" play into this?

Reference: [Image.HorizontalResolution Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.horizontalresolution(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Who decided these fields to be float? Yourself? A library that you're using? Which API?

Comment: @NayukiMinase, .NET framework, Image class

Comment: Oh! Because "resolution" refers to things like dots per inch, not pixel dimensions. We know that physical quantities are real numbers, not neat integers.

Comment: Any example? Care to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The somewhat practical answer to this question is that it is a float because the USA does not use the metric system, it measures in inches.  Rest of the world uses meters.  Having 25.4 inches in a meter does not produce nice round numbers.  Image file formats use different standards, somewhat ironically the most common image format that uses meters instead of inches was created by an American company.  The BMP file format uses pixels-per-meter.

The more technically correct answer, perhaps, is that the resolution is a design parameter of the image sensor that was used to create the image.  A physical property, like the spacing of the cells in a CCD sensor.  And affected by the lens used to project the scene onto the sensor.  Neither the sensor nor the lens are necessarily created with an evenly divisible number per inch.  Or per meter.  Chip baking factories use feature sizes that are measured in meters.  Well, nanometers.  And the focal length of the lens is often adjustable and the image processor does not account for that.

So in practice it is [just a reference number](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html) and the actual value picked is a nice round number in inches that's proportional to the number of pixels in the image.  It ensures that you have a shot at reproducing the image on another device, like a printer, with roughly the same physical size.  Very common values are 72 and 96, the default value for monitors (regardless of the monitor size) and the one you get when you created the image with a painting program.  300 and 600 are common, the resolution of cheap scanners.  Keep doubling it proportional to the amount of money you spent.

The only time I've ever seen it as a fractional number was in a hokey image conversion program that flubbed the meter-to-inch conversion.  Truncating it instead of rounding it.  Storing it in the dbase as an integer is fine when you round.  It is never infinity or NaN.

Answer (score 1):

I got confused at first because of the multiple meanings of "resolution" in the context of images.

When we talk about resolution in terms of pixel dimensions, the numbers are always integers. For example, "this TV has a resolution of 1920×1080".

When we talk about resolution in terms of pixels per inch/metre/etc., the number doesn't need to be a neat integer. We can have values like 300 DPI, 300.5 DPI, 314.159 DPI, etc.

Answer: In the context of the API field `Image.HorizontalResolution`, we are talking about physical resolution, and this is why it makes more sense for it to be a floating-point number rather than an integer.